# Assigning first, second and third int scanner values to 3 different queues

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble with assigning integers read from a dat file using scanner to different queues. After searching for a bit, I've managed to figure out how to read the int values in the file and assign them to a single queue, however what I can't figure out is how to assign the first value of the each line to a specific queue, lets say Q1, the second value of the same line to Q2, and the third value to Q3. When I try to do it I get weird values that are from completely different lines when I try to print them.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the file name with extension : ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        File file = new File(input.nextLine());

        input = new Scanner(file);

        int numPS = input.nextInt();
        int numSS = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(numPS);
        System.out.println(numSS);

        Queue<Integer> Mins = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> MinsPS = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> MinsSS = new LinkedList<>();

        while (input.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            if(input.hasNext()) 
            {
            int numofmins = input.nextInt();
            Mins.add(numofmins);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Elements of Mins:"+Mins);
        System.out.println("Elements of MinsPS:"+MinsPS);
        System.out.println("Elements of MinsSS:"+MinsSS);

         input.close();
    }
```

The contents of the .dat file are as follows:

```
3 2 
1 2 3 
3 3 5 
3 2 2 
4 3 2 
5 2 4 
0 0 0
```

With the current code, this is the output. The first queue shows all the values in the .dat file, but what I would like to have is the first second and third values of each line in each of the 3 queues respectively.

```
3
2
Elements of Mins:[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0]
Elements of MinsPS:[]
Elements of MinsSS:[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `MinsPS.add()` or `MinsSS.add()` so of course there are no items in them.

You can simply call `scanner.nextInt()` 3 times in the same loop.

For example:

```
Queue<Integer> queue1, queue2, queue3 ...
Scanner scanner = ...
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    queue1.add(scanner.nextInt());
    if (scanenr.hasNext()) queue2.add(scanner.nextInt());
    if (scanenr.hasNext()) queue3.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the file name with extension : ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        File file = new File(input.nextLine());

        input = new Scanner(file);

        int numPS = input.nextInt();
        int numSS = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(numPS);
        System.out.println(numSS);

        Queue<Integer> Mins = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> MinsPS = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> MinsSS = new LinkedList<>();
        int flag = 1;
        while (input.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            if(input.hasNext()) 
            {
              int numofmins = input.nextInt();
              switch(flag)
              {
                case 1 : 
                Mins.add(numofmins);
                break;
                case 2 :
                MinsPS.add(numofmins);
                break;
                case 3 : 
                MinsSS.add(numofmins)
                break;
              }
              flag = (flag == 3) ? 1 : flag++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Elements of Mins:"+Mins);
        System.out.println("Elements of MinsPS:"+MinsPS);
        System.out.println("Elements of MinsSS:"+MinsSS);

         input.close();
    }
```

This should fix your problem